# Angular 2 | Ho to display a minimum data of an API

Tags: angular, api, typescript

Good day, How can i display a minimum data coming from API?

lets say, my API data is Apple, Banana, Orange, Pineapple, Cherry, Strawberry.

and i want only to show 5 of them.

here's how i call my data.

```
<div *ngFor="let apidata of data">
  <div *ngIf="apidata.AssignmentNumber[0] == 1" class="box">
      <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
        <span id="AssignmentNumber" [ngStyle]="{'color': apidata.AssignmentNumber[1] == 1 ? '#FF8C00' : 'green'}">{{apidata.AssignmentNumber}}</span>
      </div>
      <div id="arrow" (click)="this.clickMe =! this.clickMe"></div>
      <div [ngClass]="(this.clickMe==true)?'box-details':'box-details-toggle'">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a map method after your api call to limit the amount returned `.map(res => res.slice(0, 5))`

Comment: got it bro, bat what if the rest of the list is i'll put it on readmore? like showing 5 of them then put the rest on read more and show all the fruits when i clicki t.

Comment: just like a facebook comment bro. ther is 13 Replies for example or rather 14 fruits more.. something like that.

Comment: you could store the entire array in one property. then have a display property that only shows 5 items initially

Comment: can you provide sample of it? sorry for this buy i am just new in angular 2

Comment: I posted a basic example of how you could show 5 out of x results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your api request you can limit the results you display

```
this.apiCall().subscribe(res => {
   // store full data
   this.fullData = res;
   // only show 5 results
   this.data = res.slice(0, 5);
});
```

Here is a demo plnkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/CY4UhpiE6uSv8pMqEa4H?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

of, using a variable "page" (page takes 0,1,2,3...) and num (num if the num of items)

```
<div *ngFor="item of items.slice(page*num,(page+1)*num)>
...
<div>
```